# How to have a projects treemap widget with code compliance % as squares color in sonarcube 5

Tags: widget, sonarqube, treemap

We've recently moved to sonarcube 5 and our projects treemap widget which display all projects by colored squares became all grey :-(

On our previous version of sonar, square size was the number of line of code and color was the code compliance (green is good compliance, red is really bad).

it seems that this colored indicator is not available anymore, I’ve try many other (like SQALE or technical debt) but none give a good result (with SQALE, all projects are green because granularity seems too small).

Some plugins exist but are all deprecated
http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Issues+Density+Plugin http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Violation+Density+Plugin

Is there a way to have the same functionality as the previous sonar version?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Same here, Technical debt ratio is all green - possibly because we've got a slimmed down profile with only the rules we really care about.  Maintainability is barely any better and quality gate status is just binary so it's not useful either